# Как узнать, запущен MediaPlayer.prepareAsync() или нет?

Tags: mediaplayer, android

При нажатии на кнопку запускаю `MediaPlayer.prepareAsync()`, при втором нажатии выдает ошибку.

Как проверить, запущен ли уже prepare?

```
  btnPlayVideo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
            if ("что сюда вставить?"){
                 mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы вам советовал использовать внешний флаг в связке с:

```
mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(....);   
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(...);
```

Код:

```
    btnPlayVideo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
                btnPlayVideo.setClickable(false);
                mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    }

mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                btnPlayVideo.setClickable(true);
                //do something
                return true;
            }
        });

    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                btnPlayVideo.setClickable(true);
                mp.start();
            }
        });
```